# Start .NET installation with VBScript and wait for completition

Tags: .net, vbscript

Since I have to run my .NET app from an USB Stick, I need a way to check if .NET is installed.

I create this VBScript (in Win10) but it doesn't wait for the installer to finish, where I wrong

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell
Dim value

On Error resume next

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
value = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release")

' check for .NET Framework 4.5.1 -> 378xxx

If ((Err.Number <> 0) Or (Clng(value) < 379000)) Then
    ' .NET 4.5.1 is not istalled....install it (and wait for completition)
    MsgBox("Install .NET")
    oShell.Run "NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe", 1, True
End If

oShell.Exec("MyApp.exe")
```

Comment: Installer might launch child processes which are not tracked by `.Run` method. You may examine that in any process explorer. Why not just to make your .Net app portable with .Net Framework included within package? Most of portable app creation soft support such feature.

Comment: Hi @omegastripes, in fact this was my goal. How can I include the Framewotk in my package? Simply copy the assemblies?

Comment: The point is to make your app portable. Some time ago I used former Spoon Studio for such purposes, IIRC it [allows to embed different runtime environments as .NET Framework, Java, Flash, Shockwave, Acrobat Reader, and SQL Server 2005 Express](https://turbo.net/docs/building/working-with-turbo-studio).

Comment: @Barzo No, you are wrong, I tested on Windows 7 64 bit and your code works!

Comment: @Barzo I will show you an another way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want your script to wait for the .NET Framework installer to complete, your another option should be a **continuous loop.**

Take a look at the following script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell
Dim value
Dim PackageName

PackageName = "NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"

Function IsProcessRunning(StrProcess)
  Dim Process
  IsProcessRunning = False
  For Each Process in GetObject("winmgmts://.").InstancesOf("Win32_process")
    If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(StrProcess) Then
    IsProcessRunning = True
    Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function

On Error Resume Next

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Value = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release")

'Check for .NET Framework 4.5.1 -> 378xxx
If ((Err.Number <> 0) Or (Clng(Value) < 379000)) Then
'.NET 4.5.1 is not istalled....install it (and wait for completition)
  MsgBox("Installing .NET Framework 4.5.1...")
  oShell.Run """<< ONLY ABSOLUTE PATH TO YOUR PACKAGE FILE + BACKSLASH >>" + PackageName + "", 1, False
End If

Do
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop Until IsProcessRunning(PackageName) = False

MsgBox ".NET Framework 4.5.1 has been installed successfully, Running MyApp..."
oShell.Exec("MyApp.exe")
```

This loop only uses 0 - 3 % of CPU resources and surely wait for the installer to complete or interrupt for any reason.

**NOTE:** This option will only work if main .NET Framework setup package is running as a background process until the installation completes or interrupts.

Here, as you are installing .NET Framework 4.5.1, this option should work.